# Tensorflow error: ValueError: Shapes (128, 100) and (128, 100, 139) are incompatible

Tags: keras, neural-network, lstm, tensorflow2.0, recurrent-neural-network

I try to use Functional API for my model, but i don't understand why i have error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (128, 100) and (128, 100, 139) are incompatible
```

My code:

```
input_tensor = Input(batch_input_shape=(batch_size,None))
x = Embedding(vocab_size, embed_dim)(input_tensor)
x = LSTM(rnn_neurons4, return_sequences=True, stateful=True)(x)
output_tensor = Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax')(x)
model = Model(input_tensor, output_tensor) 

model.summary()

Adam = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)
model.compile(optimizer=Adam, loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

[image: model summory]

fit code:

```
epochs = 1000
early_stop = EarlyStopping(monitor='loss', patience=25)
try:
  model.fit(dataset,epochs=epochs, callbacks=[early_stop])
  model.save('train.h5')
except KeyboardInterrupt:
  model.save('train.h5')
```

Comment: What is the shape of your data? There seems to be an inconsistency there

Answer (score 0):

I create my own function with sparse_categorical_crossential and add in model.compile